# What is the difference between fs.link and fs.symlink? Are they platform independent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, symlink

What is the difference between [fs.link](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_link_srcpath_dstpath_callback) and [fs.symlink](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_symlink_srcpath_dstpath_type_callback)?

I want to programmatically create a symbolic link to a physical file (or another symlink), and I'm on Linux, but wondered if it was possible to write a OS independant solution? What are the limitations?

#### Update

From the given answers and comments, Windows *seems* to support it.

Comment: The `link` function is described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hard-Links.html#Hard-Links

Comment: this is possible if [`fs.symlink`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_symlink_srcpath_dstpath_type_callback) wraps the creation of aliases in OS X, shortcuts in Windoze, and symlinks in GNU / Linux, which is likely.

Comment: SO has become such a place that, even an original, not opinionated, and concise question gets downvotes without explanations. Sheessh. I don't really care the the downvotes, but at least comment :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Linux systems have two kinds of links, hard and soft.

`fs.link()` is creating **hard links** through the C system call [`link()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html). From a terminal the equivalent is `ln originalName linkName`. A hard link consists of a new directory entry referencing the same file.  In listings it appears to be an ordinary file, just like the original file.  If the original file is removed, the content is **not** removed, and the hard link still works.  The area of the disk is only freed when all hard links are deleted.

`fs.symlink()` is creating **soft links**, a.k.a symbolic links through the C system call [`symlink()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html).  From a terminal the equivalent is `ln -s originalName linkName` where the `-s` tag denotes a soft/symbolic link.  A soft link creates a special kind of directory entry that points to another file.  The fact that it is a pointer is obvious when listing it, and deleting the original is sufficient to delete the content, and disrupts using the link.

I don't code on MS Windows, but [this guide on symbolic links](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) indicates that there is a `mklink` command for Windows command shell that can create either a hard (`mklink /H`) or a soft (`mklink /D`) link.  Microsoft Developer's Network -- MSDN -- has entries for system functions [CreateSymbolicLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363878(v=vs.85).aspx) and [CreateHardLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx) which may provide more information about what is happening at a lower level.

On Mac, [developer.apple.com's page for ln](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ln.1.html) shows they have the BSD version of the `ln` link creation terminal command in Mac OSX 10.9, supporting both hard and soft links.

Comment: Are both these functions work on Windows? I mean, there's a mention of a `junction` type for Windows, but does a `file` or `dir` also work? I am not on Windows so I have little experience with Node.js under that environment. Do these functions just throw an error, then?

Comment: @YanickRochon Unfortunately, I don't know.  Maybe someone else does, or you can try it. I believe node will call callbacks on the async functions and provide an error.  Also, I noted that the link creation commands in Windows had flags to indicate that a directory was being linked instead of a file.

Comment: yes, someone can clarify as I have no intention of installing Node.js on Windows, and I can't stand using a Mac.

Comment: This works on Windows.

Comment: I tested hard links on windows, but apparently, the hard links become invalid when the original file is deleted